# Firefox blocked resource due to Type mismatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, babeljs

**The resource from `http://some-address/script.jsx` was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).**
This issue I get in console of Firefox (Chrome seems doesn't care about it).
Here's a screenshot of console:
[image]
I searched for a while trying to find how tot fix it, but failed. Here's the HTML part of the code.
[image]

As far as I've understood the problem is due to **type="text/babel"**. But if I would change it to type="text/javascript" then Babel doesn't transpile the script to ES5.

Answer (score 3):

this is because your server send response header `X-Content-Type-Options: "nosniff"`, remove it or change mime type for `jsx` to `text/babel` with `.htaccess` it can done by adding `AddType text/babel jsx`